# Redirect a domain using bind9

Tags: debian, bind, redirection

I researched various topics before asking. But found my solution. So sorry if I could have used another topic.

My problem:

I have a fixed ip and server ip with another fixed.

Primary Server: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (domain.com)

And in my personal fixed IP I have a server with two machines. Subdomains point to my fixed ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.fix

sub1.domain.com: xxx.xxx.xxx.fix sub2.domain.com: xxx.xxx.xxx.fix

But internally have it:

sub1.domain.com: 10.1.1.253 sub2.domain.com: 10.1.1.252

It turns out that my router has everything that comes from port 80 to the IP 10.1.1.253. It is possible to configure bind9 to enter sub2.domain.com when I send it to ip 10.1.1.252?

This image show my problem: http://s7.postimg.org/f1d0hlv9n/problem.jpg

Comment: You can't do this with bind. Research proxys. Read [about].

Comment: Thanks lain...  I will search. After i will post in here to help another people.